# How to surf the web without cookies from code

Tags: python, dart, web

I was try to scrape some links from the web via google search.

Let's say my query is [`games site:pastebin.com`].

I was trying this in both `python` and `dart` but the result i got was that i need to login in for it and i don't ant to use cookies.

So, is there any way to get the result of `https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Apastebin.com+games` from code block without cookies?

The Code I Tried:
<kbd>Python 3.9.5</kbd>

```py
import requests

req = requests.get("https://www.google.com/search?q=games+site%3Apastebin.com")
```

Comment: Can you share what code you tried? You dont need to login to google to query it, and there is at least Python libraries that do this for you

Comment: cookies are useful for storing data when scraping the web. That being said maybe you can use a web driver like selenium to drive your task.

Answer (score 0):

That fully depends on the website you are trying to access. Some pages won't allow you to use certain features from their page without cookies at all, some do. For the purpose you are trying to achieve, I'd rather recommend using a search API, which doesn't require cookies - since cookies are normally for regular users.

Google usually asfaik doesn't like it if you scrape their content using scripts.

As mentioned before, you can look for alternative search engines, which don't require cookie usage